# Applying Gaussian filter to 1D data "by hands" using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, convolution

I have a nonuniformly sampled data that I am trying to apply a Gaussian filter to. I am using python's numpy library to solve this. The data is of XY type, here is how it looks like:

```
[[ -0.96       390.63523024]
[ -1.085      390.68523024]
[ -1.21       390.44023023]
...
[-76.695      390.86023024]
[-77.105      392.51023024]
[-77.155      392.10023024]]
```

And [here](https://kth.box.com/s/zdyyhknska5oiawywtgd4nkrsfygp78d) is a link to the whole *.npz file.

Here is my approach:

1. I start with defining a Gaussian function
2. Then I start scanning the data with a while loop along the X axis
3. Within each step of the loop:

   - I select a portion of data that is within two cutoff lengths
   - shift the X axis of the selected data portion to make it symmetrical around 0
   - calculate my Gaussian function at every point, multiply with corresponding Y values, sum and divide by number of elements
4. Move to next point

Here is how code looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xy = np.load('1D_data.npz')['arr_0']

def g_func(xx, w=1.0):
    a = 0.47 * w
    return (1 / a) * np.exp((xx / a) ** 2 * (-np.pi))

x, y, x_, y_ = xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], [], []

counter, xi, ww = 0, x[0], 1.0
while xi > np.amin(x):

    curr_x = x[(x < xi) & (x >= xi - 2 * ww)]
    g, ysel = [], []
    for i, els in enumerate(curr_x):
        xil = els - curr_x[0] + abs(curr_x[0] - curr_x[-1]) / 2
        g.append(g_func(xil, ww))
        ysel.append(y[counter + i])

    y_.append(np.sum(np.multiply(g, ysel)) / len(g))
    x_.append(xi)

    counter += 1
    xi = x[counter]

plt.plot(x, y, '-k')
plt.plot(x_, y_, '-r')
plt.show()
```

The output doesn't look right though. (See the fig below) Even if discarding the edges, the convolution is very noisy and the values do not seem to correspond to the data. What am I possibly doing wrong?

[image: black - original data, red - calculated convolution]

Comment: I know this may be a stupid question, but is there a specific reason why you're not simply using scipy's `gaussian_filter1d()`?

Comment: @Asmus I wanted to have my own solution with tuneable shape of the window function. And it doesn't look like a very complicated task.. can't get where I am doing it wrong. Thanks for the comment, anyway!

Comment: So do you want to write _everything_ by hand, or would using `np.convolve()` with a "manual" filter function be ok, too?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about doing it _fully manual_. Are you trying to say it is a too hard task?

Comment: No, not necessarily. I think you will learn a lot of helpful things about python/numpy/coding along the way, but you'll also likely end up with a not-as-efficient/widely compatible solution ;-) I'll try look at it again tomorrow, but so far I admittedly had a tough time understanding your code (that's not necessarily your fault!). Could you perhaps comment on what the line with `np.sum(np.multiply(g, ysel)) / len(g)` is supposed to do?

Comment: Sure: I build up my `y_` list with convolution (moving average) values at this point. `ysel` is a list of selected Y values, and `g` is  a list with gaussian function calculated at the same points. I multiply these two lists element wise using `numpy.multiply`. Then sum up all of the elements of the resultant list using `numpy.sum` and finally divide by the number of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made one mistake in your code:

**Before multiplying `g` with `y_sel`, `y_sel` is not centered.**

The reason why `y_sel` should be centered is because we want to add the relative differences weighted by the Gaussian to the entry at the center. If you multiply `g` with `y_sel` directly, not just the values of the neighboring entries within the window, but also the value of the center entry will be weighted by the Gaussian. This will definitely change the function values dramatically.

Below is my solution using `numpy`

```
def g_func(xx, w=1.0):
    mean = np.mean(xx)
    a = 0.47 * w
    return (1 / a) * np.exp(((xx-mean) / a) ** 2 * (-np.pi))


def get_convolution(array,half_window_size):
    
    array = np.concatenate((np.repeat(array[0],half_window_size),
                            array,
                            np.repeat(array[-1],half_window_size)))
    window_inds = [list(range(ind-half_window_size,ind+half_window_size+1)) \
                   for ind in range(half_window_size,len(array)-half_window_size)]
    
    return np.take(array,window_inds)

xy = np.load('1D_data.npz')['arr_0']
x, y = xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1]

half_window_size = 4
x_conv = np.apply_along_axis(g_func,axis=1,arr=get_convolution(x,half_window_size=half_window_size))
y_conv = get_convolution(y,half_window_size=half_window_size)
y_mean = np.mean(y_conv,axis=1)
y_centered = y_conv - y_mean[:,None]
smoothed = np.sum(x_conv*y_centered,axis=1) / (half_window_size*2) + y_mean

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
ax.plot(x, y, '-k')
ax.plot(x, smoothed, '-r')
```

running the code, the output is

[image: output]

---

**UPDATE**

In order to unify `w` with `half_window_size`, here is one possibility, the idea is to let the standard deviation of the Gaussian to be `2*half_window_size`

```
def g_func(xx):
    
    std = len(xx)
    mean = np.mean(xx)
    return 1 / (std*np.sqrt(2*np.pi)) * np.exp(-1/2*((xx-mean)/std)**2)


def get_convolution(array,half_window_size):
    
    array = np.concatenate((np.repeat(array[0],half_window_size),
                            array,
                            np.repeat(array[-1],half_window_size)))
    window_inds = [list(range(ind-half_window_size,ind+half_window_size+1)) \
                   for ind in range(half_window_size,len(array)-half_window_size)]
    
    return np.take(array,window_inds)

xy = np.load('1D_data.npz')['arr_0']
x, y = xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1]

half_window_size = 4
x_conv = np.apply_along_axis(g_func,axis=1,arr=get_convolution(x,half_window_size=half_window_size))
y_conv = get_convolution(y,half_window_size=half_window_size)
y_mean = np.mean(y_conv,axis=1)
y_centered = y_conv - y_mean[:,None]
smoothed = np.sum(x_conv*y_centered,axis=1) / (half_window_size*2) + y_mean

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
ax.plot(x, y, '-k')
ax.plot(x, smoothed, '-r')
```

Comment: @ meTchaikovsky thanks for the feedback and efforts! I will reflect in two comments to make it more ordered. First regarding feedback to my solution: 
**1.** I actually substract the mean, I do it inside each loop of the cycle: `xil = els - curr_x[0] + abs(curr_x[0] - curr_x[-1]) / 2` 
**2.** This part I didn't understand, why do I need to center `ysel` before multiplication with Gaussian?

Comment: Regarding your solution: 
**1.** `half_window_size` In reality window size is defined by width of Gaussian, i.e. `w` parameter. Otherwise filtering is kind of weird: it depends upon two parameters 'half_window_size' defined in the main program and 'w' defined within function definition
**2.** `y_centered` I still can't understand why is it required to center the selected Y values before multiplying with Gaussian bell. Could you perhaps comment on it a bit more?
At the same time I liked your approach with introducing `get_convolution` function for data selection. Nice!

Comment: @Bulat You're welcome, I'm glad I helped. Sorry for the first mistake in my original post, I have deleted it in my updated post. As for the reason why `y_sel` should be centered, there are two reasons: **1**. If you don't subtract the mean, the center value will also be weighted by the Gaussian. **2**. what we want is to add the relative differences weighted by the Gaussian to the center.

Comment: thanks for the update! Regarding the second comment though. I thought on how to make the `half_window_size` parameter in your code dependable on the width of the Gaussian. Here is one suggestion: **1.** define the value of `w` somewhere within your code **2.** substitute the line `half_window_size = 4` with `half_window_size = int(x.shape[0] / (abs(x[0] - x[-1]) / ww))` **3.** add corresponding `w` argument definition to the line with `np.apply_along_axis`. What do you think?

Comment: @Bulat You're welcome :) I think you can simply drop `w`, and replace it with `half_window_size`. Check out my updated post.